# What is a javascript MVC framework

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have found a few links talking about which MVC framework is better, but not any actually describing the ideology behind it.

I am familiar with MVC framework for backend, as I use django (the MTV framework).

I essentially want to understand the mapping of each of Models, Views and Controller in client side javascript MVC framework (I always relate model to something mapping to database in my mind), and how is the code structured if I were to use such a framework.

Comment: Your question body doesn't correlate with your question. What are you asking, really? Could you perhaps elaborate a bit?

Comment: MVC is about the separation between business logic, presentation and the necessary glue inbetween. This applies equally well to backend as to frontend programming.

Comment: @limelights sorry for the incomplete question. I was typing the question in two tabs and mistakenly submitted the incomplete one

Comment: @nik-v No need to apologize :) It's difficult sometimes in this day and age! Unfortunately it's a bit too broad of a question. I would suggest Addy Osmanis TODOMVC project if you want to learn more!

Comment: "Model" !== "database". The model is the *business logic*, i.e. anything the app "can do". In the case of a client-side Javascript app that would typically be to handle communication with the server to "make things happen" there. The View would be the part that is actively changing and updating the DOM elements. The Controller is the part that handles events and triggers Model actions and View updates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The MVC pattern can be used in an n-tier architecture to design the presentation tier, with the new JavaScript-based UI, the presentation tier can now be implemented exclusively in JavaScript so that's an example of why one would need a MVC JavaScript framework.

In this article from [Microsoft pattern & practices](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647343.aspx), they talk about using the MVC pattern inside the Presentation Layer of a web application.